# when bot not in channel, bot will auto join to specific channel. discord js

Tags: discord.js

i made this code for my music bot, but idk how bot can check when bot not in voice channel, bot will automatic connect back to specific channel like the id. but when bot using in another voice channel, the bot not back to the specific voice channel i made. idk how to code interval, loop, or check bot in voice or not.

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Hello ${client.user.username} is now online!`);

  let channel = client.channels.cache.get("720137811587629119");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  setInterval(function() {

  channel.join()
  .then(connection => console.log('Connected'))
  .catch(console.error);
}, 30000)

  let botStatus = [
    `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`,
    "s,help or s,h",
    `Over ${client.users.cache.size} users!`,
    `Over ${client.channels.cache.size} channels!`
  ]
  
  setInterval(function() {
    let status = botStatus[Math.floor(Math.random() * botStatus.length)];
    client.user.setActivity(status, {type: "PLAYING"});
  
    }, 5000)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `voiceStateUpdate` event on Client to detect when your bot has disconnected from a voice channel. Here's an example:

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.id !== client.user.id) return; // do nothing if it's not your bot
  if (oldState.channel.id === "720137811587629119" && !newState.channel) { // check if the bot was disconnected from 720137811587629119
    newState.setChannel("720137811587629119");
  }
}
```

Comment: where i put the code? replace channel.join() ?
i need the bot always join that channel, when bot not used